# What is the meaning of: 「ばえていくけん」?

Tags: dialects, phrases

The complete phrase is: 「日本中で、ばえていくけん！」.

With the けん at the end, I thought it might have been something from a Kyushu dialect, but the person who said this is from Tottori.

The only part I'm really having trouble with is the verb 「ばえていく」. I tried looking up ばえる and ばう as potential verb roots, but they don't seem to exist.  Has anyone every heard of this?

Comment: 辞書にありました--> [鳥取弁「ばえる」](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B0%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B)

Comment: @Chocolate I challenge you to make an answer out of that before I steal it and do it myself ;)

Comment: @ssb いあいあいあそんな～おまかせします～

Comment: @Chocolate Clearly, I need a new dictionary (^^ ありがとうございました。本当に助かりました！

Comment: けん is also used in certain parts of 四国 and 中国 although I'm not sure exactly where. I'm not surprised if it's used Tottori. I would be great to have an isogloss map, but I haven't been able to find any.

Answer (score 3):

ばえる means 騒ぐ in 鳥取弁, the dialect of [Tottori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tottori_Prefecture).

けん is mostly used in the 九州 area and some parts of 四国 and can mean a range of things. I am most familiar with から and some kinds of よ:

#### から

- 今日は寒い**けん**、コートを着た方がいいよ
- 今日は寒い**から**、コートを着た方がいいよ

#### よ

- お茶いれた**けん**
- お茶いれた**よ**

Or

- いや、昨日めちゃめちゃ面白かったんだ**よ**な〜
- いや、昨日めちゃおもろかった**けん**な〜